# React production build unused code splitting chunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I run `npm run build` a build directory is created with js chunks. I have noticed that there is a `[number].[hash].chunk.js` file that is not listed as one of the `entrypoints` in the `asset-manifest.json` file.

Instead, this file appears to be referenced in the `runtime-main.[hash].js` file.

What is the purpose of this file? I have noticed that in it's map file it references `web-vitals.js`. Do I need to make sure that my application will be able to access this file? Is it critical to the application's performance?

This is a react app was created with typescript using `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

Comment: If it's referenced in runtime-main, why conclude it's unused? Have you looked up what web-vitals does? And what are you planning to do with an answer - _not_ serve that file? Why?

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I deploy the files to production, the path to reference the js files is different than the auto generated `/static/js` path which is declared in the runtime file. If I need this file, I need to figure out a way to change the reference path in the runtime file to be able to reliably get the js file.

Comment: You should probably [edit] that context into the question. Is this a CRA app? Did you read e.g. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths?

Answer (score -1):

At build time your bundler (webpack) will determine what code is necessary for the main entry bundle and which code can be loaded later (aka. lazy loading). It will also determine which files are shared by different entry points and will bundle them as a shared asset. This allows your application to load quicker on initial load - only loading the resources it needs when they're needed.

There are complex algorithms which determine how to split code in a way which is beneficial to both end users and your server/network. In general, don't try to analyze it. You can trust that the people writing the algorithms are smart and striving for the greater good, and it's always getting better.

> NOTE: I used to work for a company that built a bundler and implemented code splitting long before webpack, rollup, and friends came along. The bundler was used for years for the likes of Sam's Club, Levi's, and some fruit company. It did not take long for webpack and rollup to surpass the one we had built, but I still have a pretty intimate understanding of how it all works, and the guys who built it were some of the smartest people I've ever met. You don't really need to understand the output files - I highly doubt there are any unnecessary files being generated.